# Use only sed/BASH to convert expanded IPv6 into reverse nibble arpa for PTR

Tags: bash, sed

I have many IPv6 addresses I work with, but let's say today it's: `2001:abc::1`

I already can expand it using BASH to: `2001:0abc:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001`

**I need to take that *expanded* IPv6 and reverse it into a nibble (plus the arpa string) for my PTR, so it looks like this:**

`1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.c.b.a.0.1.0.0.2.ip6.arpa`

I'll allow `awk` or other lower-stack answers to benefit the community, BASH and functions are okay, but a one-line `sed` would rock my world.

---

*Note: There was discussion about this being a "real problem". My scripts only use `sed`, no `awk` anywhere, and lean toward `/sh` more than `/bash`. I consider the skills needed to maintain the scripts part of a de facto "dependency" and I avoid `awk` for that reason. However, to be useful to the community, `awk` answers should be welcome here. A BASH function not using `awk` would also be welcome.*

Comment: I understand preferring built-in or standardized (and guaranteed-available) tools, but unless the existing `awk`-based answers are relying on `gawk`- or other vendor-provided extensions, `awk` is just as POSIX-standardized and "low-in-the-stack" as `sed` is.

Comment: Okay, I welcome and will upvote an `awk` answer for your reason, but I will only "accept" `sed`. And, I will change my question to reflect this. ty

Comment: The rationale for understanding rigidity in tool choice is significant to topicality -- we require that a question be based on "an actual problem" that you face. If you need to write code that's portable to systems without non-standard tools, that's clearly an actual problem. If you just want to know if an answer using only `sed` is possible for the sake of curiosity, that's a bit more open to debate.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This is a real problem, not just curiosity. I'll accept other low-stack answers, as I just now edited. But, the software I have written over the last five years very specifically has only `sed` and not one single `awk` command because I want my code to be as slim and low-dependency as possible. Also, I have had some situations where awk wasn't available in the past. But, to respect your point, I have indeed already edited my question to allow an awk answer. Thank you for that clarification.

Comment: You accepted an answer that relies on GNU sed. You're far less likely to have GNU sed than a POSIX awk available on any given UNIX system. You're also far more likely to have a convoluted mess in your code if you're favoring sed at all costs since other than `s/old/new` an awk solution is typically clearer, simpler, more efficient, more robust, more potable, easier to enhance, and often briefer than a sed attempt at solving the same problem.

Comment: @EdMorton Okay. If awk is becoming the thing, I'd welcome an awk solution.

Comment: awk isn't becoming the thing, it has been the thing for anything other than s/old/new since the mid 1970s. People use sed for anything else just for the mental exercise.

Comment: @EdMorton That is awesome to know, sir. I'd love it if you would provide an awk solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184919/discussion-between-jesse-steele-and-ed-morton).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rarpa() {
  local idx s=${1//:}
  for (( idx=${#s} - 1; idx>=0; idx-- )); do
    printf '%s.' "${s:$idx:1}"
  done
  printf 'ip6.arpa\n'
}

rarpa '2001:0abc:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001'
```

...emits as output:

```
1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.c.b.a.0.1.0.0.2.ip6.arpa
```

Comment: One caveat -- this really is a *bash* answer right now; making it work as well with `/bin/sh` would mean changing the syntax used for the math and (more problematically) for indexing into the string; I'd probably switch to awk if given the requirement.

Comment: Yes, I see that. I changed the "correct" answer to the one-line sed. But, I did use yours in my code for now. Your comments have taught me a lot. I'm in Asia, going to sleep and will read comments later.

Answer (score 2):

A GNU sed one-liner, probably mostly to demonstrate how you shouldn't use sed for this:

```
sed 's/://g;s/^.*$/\n&\n/;tx;:x;s/\(\n.\)\(.*\)\(.\n\)/\3\2\1/;tx;s/\n//g;s/\(.\)/\1./g;s/$/ip6.arpa/'
```

Broken up and commented:

```
# Remove all the colons
s/://g

# Embed line between two newlines
s/^.*$/\n&\n/

# Reset flag tested by t
tx

# Label to jump to
:x

# Swap two characters
s/\(\n.\)\(.*\)\(.\n\)/\3\2\1/

# Jump to label if substitution did something
tx

# Remove newlines
s/\n//g

# Insert period after each character
s/\(.\)/\1./g

# Append rest of desired string
s/$/ip6.arpa/
```

The line reversal technique is taken from the [GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Reverse-chars-of-lines.html).

The only thing in there that actually requires GNU sed is inserting newlines with just `\n`; if instead of `s/^.*$/\n&\n/`, you use literal newlines as in

```
s/^.*$/\
&\
/
```

the script should run with any sed.

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk in any shell on any UNIX system:

```
$ awk '{
    gsub(/:/,"")
    for (i=length($0); i>0; i--) {
        printf "%s.", substr($0,i,1)
    }
    print "ip6.arpa"
}' file
1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.c.b.a.0.1.0.0.2.ip6.arpa
```

Comment: A gentleman and a scholar, sir! I will sleep on this and think of a way to rewrite my question to make these more fitting while keeping to my theme. Basically, you're telling me I need to rewrite almost 300 scripts, lol. I'll give some good though, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. You might find you don't need 300 separate scripts if you have a couple of awk scripts instead.

Comment: Maybe, but, I've basically recreated "command line C-Panel" using small Shell scripts and am planning a Node.js GUI later. The rest API would be the same, but it sounds like I would need to rewrite it all in awk to make it more robust. I'm up to it, lol.